# Remove everything after a specific string but keep the first

Tags: php

I have a string like "Car version XXXX".

I want to remove all after "version" but keep this first part. The final should be "Car version"

Currently, I managed to do this:

```
$version = "Car version 15282";

$version = substr($version, 0, strpos($version, "version"));

echo $version;
```

But it removes the string "version" also and I need to keep it. In the web I only see example to remove after the character including this last.

How to achieve this in PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add on the length of the string you are searching for because `strlen()` gives you the index of where the string `version` starts.

```
$version = "Car version 15282";

$version = substr($version, 0, strpos($version, "version")+strlen("version"));

echo $version;
```

Gives Result

```
Car version
```

Comment: Hello RiggsFolly, thanks for your answer ! 
I want to understand well strpos determine the *start* of the string and strlen the lenght of the string , So I need to append the lenght to get the end of the word ?

Comment: Yes, thats the reason

Answer (score 2):

Since you know what you're looking for you just need one function:

```
$version = "Car version 15282";
$find = "version";
$version = strstr($version, $find, true) . $find;
```

If it could get more complex, match and capture `()` everything up to and including what you want to find `.*` and `$find` and replace that and everything after `.*` with what you captured `$1`:

```
$version = preg_replace("/(.*$find).*/", "$1", $version);
```